# AEM Pages served by dispatcher do not match Author or Publish server content

Tags: aem

We have created content on an AEM author server and published the pages.  The content shows up correctly on the publish server.  However, when we try to reach the pages "live" as served from the dispatcher, they are missing some images and all of the css formatting.

We have tried flushing the dispatcher, but that didn't seem to work.  Any hints on how to proceed with fixing this?

Comment: Are requests for css files and images allowed by the dispatcher filters? Checking the dispatcher logs should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs? What happens if you request this image directly on Dispatcher? You need to put a lot more detail in here to be a useful quesiton

Comment: thanks, yes there isn't anything in the logs that shows an error or other strange activity. that's why were were kind of stumped.   I'll try requesting an image directly from dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing images, css, js could be due to blocked/misconfigured paths in your dispatcher. Check your dispatcher access logs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.  In case it helps anyone else, the problem was that the dispatcher flush job wasn't actually working.  We had to go in and manually delete the designs folder tree and force the dispatcher to rebuild files from publish.

A second problem was due to some file extensions not being allowed.  We updated one of the config files to allow png and ttf files, so all the images and fonts would load successfully.